# Android featureDetector out of Bounds

Tags: java, android, image, opencv, image-size

at the moment Iam working with Android Opencv. Iam Using the featureDetector with the Method FAST to find KeyPoints on an 240 x 320 Image.

```
    //create a keypoint mat
    MatOfKeyPoint keyPoints = new MatOfKeyPoint();
    //create feature detector
    FeatureDetector fd = FeatureDetector.create(FeatureDetector.FAST);
    //detect feature points
    fd.detect(image, keyPoints);

    //return feature points
    return keyPoints;
```

Next I will extract the points from the KeyPoints after Matching them:

```
    DMatch[] matchesArray = matches.toArray();
    Vector<Point> pointsVec1 = new Vector<Point>();
    Vector<Point> pointsVec2 = new Vector<Point>();

    for(int i = 0; i < matchesArray.length; i++)
    {
        pointsVec1.add(keyPoints1.toArray()[matchesArray[i].queryIdx].pt);
        pointsVec2.add(keyPoints2.toArray()[matchesArray[i].trainIdx].pt);
    }

    points1.fromList(pointsVec1);
    points2.fromList(pointsVec2);
```

Later I try to get the pixel color of these points, doing this:

```
    Point[] pointsArray = points.toArray();
    Vector<byte[]> colorVector = new Vector<byte[]>();
    for(int i = 0; i< pointsArray.length; i++)
    {
        Point point = pointsArray[i];
        byte[] color = new byte[4];
        image.get((int) point.x, (int) point.y, color);
        colorVector.add(color);
    }
    return colorVector;
```

Iam still wondering because there are Points out of border of the Image. For example I found this point by debugging: (308.0, 16.0). By an 240 x 340 Image this point is not in the image. There are more Point of these. I checked already the featureExtractor and the Point is already containing there. So i get a color of R = 0, G = 0, B = 0.

So my question is: 
Where does this Points come from?
Have I to filter them on my own or is there something like Threshhold solution in the function?
Or I have to switch x and y or change the conversion of the Points?

In the end it is a small problem but i cant explain myself where doese they come from!

So thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have not switch `x <-> y` or `row <-> col`.